# Record absolute time in the background and display related time in the frontend

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a database of `posts`. For each `post`, I want to save its last-opened time by different users. So I decide to save in the backend the absolute time (ie, by `moment()`) and display in the frontend the related time (ie, by `fromNow()`, eg, `2 days ago`).

In the backend:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ... ...
  lastOpens: { type: Array, default: [] },
});

PostSchema.methods.updateLastOpens = function (userId, cb) {
  ... ...
  this.lastOpens.push({ time: moment(), userId: userId });
};
```

In the frontend:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(post.lastOpens[j].time))
var x = post.lastOpens[0].time.fromNow()
```

However, the first line in the frontend displays a very long object `{"_isValid":true,"_d":"2017-04-20T02:42:50.932Z","_locale":{"_dayOfMonthOrdinalParseLenient":{},...`. And the second like shows `TypeError: post.lastOpens[0].time.fromNow is not a function`.

Does anyone know where is wrong and how to achieve this?

Comment: You are pushing a moment.js object into the array then stringifying it, so what you see is the stringified moment object, not a date. You should probably push `{time: moment().fomat('YYYY-MM-DD'), ...}` or similar.

Comment: I stringified that in `alert()`, but not in `var x = post.lastOpens[0].time.fromNow()`.

Comment: Yes, but what you should think about is that the backend will serialize the object, hence the long Json you see, and send it to the front end. when it arrives at the front end, it is no longer a moment object. it is a normal json object which has the data but doesn't have the methods. I would recreate the moment() from the contents of .time in the front end and retry the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are getting from the backend is possibly not a `moment object`. Hence you unable to call `fromNow` function on that. To call fromNow, you can convert your data to a moment object by passing `_d` in the `moment constructor` and then call `fromNow` on that object like this

```
var x = moment(post.lastOpens[j].time._d).fromNow()
```